# Binary Search on Linked List (using recursion)

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, struct, linked-list

I have implemented a program that checks if a number given exists on a linked list or not, but I have encounter a problem during execution; nothing appears when i input some value that doesn't exist on my list, it seems to me that my program is stuck in a infinite loop.
can anyone help me to improve my algorithm ? 
thanks in advance!
you can check the whole code here : https://github.com/mmed17/BinarySearchRecursively

```
typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
}list;
typedef struct info
{
    int element;
    bool found;
}binary;
list * find_mid(list *head,list *last)
{
    list *slow=head;
    list *fast=head->next;
    if(head==NULL)  return NULL;
    if(fast==last)  return head;
    while(fast!=last)
    {
        fast=fast->next;
        if(fast!=last)
        {
            fast=fast->next;
            slow=slow->next;
        }
    }
    return slow;
}
binary * binary_search(list *head,list *last,binary *temp)
{
     list *mid=find_mid(head,last);
    if(last != head)
    {
        if(mid->data < temp->element)
            head=mid->next;
        else if(mid->data > temp->element)
            last=mid;
        else
        {
            temp->found=true;
            return temp;
        }
        return binary_search(head,last,temp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Binary search a *linked list*? That makes no sense...

Comment: We are talking about "searching" here, not "binary searching".

Comment: Yes, binary search on a linked list sounds wrong. For what it's worth: In `fast = head->next`, you access `head` before checking for `NULL`. (You should probably assign `fast = head` anyway.)